# MySQL Beginner - how to parse a string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to parse strings (e.g. "\Maintenance\Maintain\Plumbing\Grease") with a column name "PATH". The desired output should be "Plumbing"

I think i can use substring_index... thoughts?

Comment: what's the pattern? Do all the rows share the same pattern? Better explain more.

Comment: Please add more examples and what do you want to achieve? Always the word after the 3rd occurence of "/", always the second to last word, ...?

Comment: If you know it's always the 3rd occurence of "\" you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX(PATH, '\', 3) and then use this index to split the string. We need more information to provide a general answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, '\\', -2), '\\', 1)
```